# How do I search for all properties in a .find using express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an express app and I'm trying to create a search query.

```
exports.searchProperty = async (req, res) => {

  const query1 = {
    county: req.query.county || $all,
    bedrooms: {
      $gte: parseInt(req.query.minbed) || 1,
      $lte: parseInt(req.query.maxbed) || 10,
    },
  };

  const property = await Property.find(query1);
  res.json(property);
};
```

As you can see in the query1 object, I have a county property. I want to eitheir search the database for the defined county in the url, **or if the user fails to select a county**, as a fallback. I search for every county (ie every document.) Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

to search for all the counties, just don't mention it in the query

we can add some logic before structuring the object

something like this

```
const minbed = req.query.minbed || 1;
const maxbed = req.query.maxbed || 10;

const query1 = {
    bedrooms: {
        $gte: minbed,
        $lte: maxbed
    }
};

if (req.query.county) {
    // just add the county to the search only if it exists
    query1.county = req.query.county
}

// then do the query
const property = await Property.find(query1);
res.json(property);
```

hope it helps

Comment: I only want to search for all counties if a county hasn't been selected. It's essentially a default or a fallback option.

Comment: okay if you want to search for all the counties, you don't need to add it to the query, could you try the above code?

Comment: is there a county called 'all' in your db?, or do you mean all the counties exist in db?

Comment: If no query is provided I want to return all documents. There is no county called all, but as such I want to return every possible county